# To show an alert when application just enter into background

Tags: iphone

I just want to show an alert when user just quit the application before application entering the background, how can I do that??

If I show the alert in `applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` method then this alert will be shown when we again resume the application, but I need to show the alert before the application enters the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this, and rightly so. When the user presses the home button, *they go to the home screen*. This is a fundamental part of the iOS user experience. Nothing stops the home button working.

Answer (score 0):

[applicationWillResignActive](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a) and [applicationWillTerminate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate%3a) may be of interest to this general question—but you can't present anything into the UI once the home button is pressed. These methods do let you briefly run any critical code however, while the home screen is being presented to the user.

Comment: there is no method of name applicationWillEnterBackground, you might be talking about applicationWillEnterForeground method, anyways thanks, hoping for some more responses with the solution....

Comment: not possible to do something with UI when u just pressed home button, anyways thanks for your responses, have a good day:)